# xparse command definition vs \newcommand

Tags: macros, best-practices, xparse

Maybe my question is too broad, but I'd really like to know: what is best to use (and why) between `xparse` command definition (e.g. `\NewDocumentCommand`) and LaTeX "standard" definitions (e.g. `\newcommand`)?

When I started with LaTeX I learnt that LaTeX definitions are more convenient than TeX plain definitions (e.g. `\def`) for many reasons (e.g. not having the risk to inadvertently override some existing command and such).

I'm wondering if the new `xparse` definitions are better; for instance sometimes I've seen that the syntax to define a command is more clear (to me) and seems very powerful.

Are there any drawbacks? 
Thanks

Comment: The `xparse` commands are regarded as stable, but as long as you do not use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` the `\NewDocumentCommand` aren't expandable -- that's a drawback

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\newcommand` defined commands are not expandable either if they have optional arguments. (I see you had the same statement in your answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I answered rather than to use a short comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Caution: Opinion based answer ahead ;-)**

The command argument specification is a very powerful feature of `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentCommand` (and the other ones, like `\DeclareDocumentCommand` etc.) macro. (`\NewDocumentCommand` stands here for the whole bundle of such commands!)

The question if they are better (safer?) than `\newcommand` - defined macros is difficult to answer and opinion - based.

- It's easier to cope with multiple optional arguments by using `\IfValueTF` etc.
- It's easier to provide other types of optional etc. arguments
- Concerning the undelimited argument facilities `\NewDocumentCommand` is definitely more of a `\def` from plain TeX than `\newcommand`
- Since command definition checking is done as well, `xparse` commands are safer compared to `\def` concerning redefinition of macros.
- Macros defined by `xparse` commands allow for starred versions, which is very convenient for redefinition of `\section*` etc.
- In addition: Environments defined by `\NewDocumentEnvironment` can use the arguments even in the end code - section, contrary to `\newenvironment`

However, a command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't fully expandable and can not be used where a full expansion is needed, as soon as optional arguments are involved, so this might be a drawback.
But in many cases, it's possible to fall back to a simple `\newcommand` without optional argument then.

For such cases, `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` has to be used.

I started with `\def` a long time ago, then improved with `\newcommand` and nowadays use `\NewDocumentCommand` for most of my personal documents and of course, for answers here.

In conjunction with `expl3` `xparse` (which is in fact a `expl3` application package of course) is very powerful and recommendable.

Comment: If there are no optional arguments it'll be expandable anyway, so the extra feature is that it is possible to define a command that looks for optional arguments via expansion

Comment: Yes, I was confused for a moment: I frequently use optional arguments so the non-optional argument `\NewDocumentCommand` macro is rarely used by me