# \NewDocumentCommand vs \newcommand vs \NewExpandableDocumentCommand (to define a container for a text)

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion, robust-commands

In [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685240/18401) to a recent question of mine, @egreg advised `\newcommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` to define a container for a text. And I'm aware of [this (10 years old!) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98152/18401) where:

- Joseph Wright answers “Conceptually, `\NewDocumentCommand` is intended for 'package authors' to define commands”. But it is so simpler to define optional arguments (and even starred variants) with `\NewDocumentCommand` that I don't see why not advise it to document authors.
- Ulrike Fischer answers “Macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are robust, they don't get expanded when e.g. moved to the `.toc`”. But the issue with `\NewDocumentCommand` example she gave [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98165/18401) can be avoided with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`:

  ```
    \documentclass{article}
    % \usepackage{xparse}                          % <- useless nowadays

    \begin{document}
    \NewDocumentCommand\testA{}{ABC}
    \newcommand\testB{ABC}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testC}{}{ABC}   % <- added by me

    \tableofcontents

    \RenewDocumentCommand\testA{}{CDE}
    \renewcommand\testB{CDE}
    \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testC}{}{CDE} % <- added by me

    \section{\testA, \testB
    , \testC                                       % <- added by me
    }

    \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Hence I wonder why not use:

- `\NewDocumentCommand` (and friends) as document author?
- `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` to define a container for a text?

I agree that it wouldn't be ideal to mix `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`s and
`\NewDocumentCommand`s in the same preamble, the former for *variables*
(i.e. container of text i.e. macros used as storage) and the latter for
*commands*. But mixing `\newcommand`s and `\NewDocumentCommand`s would look
worse.

Moreover, the arguments in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276737/18401) also are in favor of `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

So I know this has been already discussed but, since `xparse` is now in the kernel, I'd like to know if there are still strong arguments against `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for document authors (I'm inclined to promote them in my LaTeX's courses).

### Edit

*(Here is a bit of context that might explain the current question.)*

My concern here is what to teach to beginners or intermediate users of LaTeX. I used to teach `\newcommand{\dst}{Dostoïevsky}` as an example of a nice feature of LaTeX for a student who has to write a long report on Dostoïevsky. And, of course, I didn't stop there: for students in history, I used to teach:

- `\newcommand{\century}[1]{\textsc{#1}\ieme{}~siècle}` (sorry in French, “siècle” being “century” and with the `babel-french` feature `\ieme`),
- and even `\newcommand{\century}[2][\ieme]{\textsc{#2}#1~siècle}` since, in French, there is an exception only for the 1<sup>st</sup> century (ignoring negative centuries): `\century[\ier]{i}`.

And I was after a way to replace this by the more modern, flexible and, I hoped, uniform way of defining variables/commands: the “`xparse`”' way.

Comment: The downside of `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for just "container for text" is just the extra overhead (which on any reasonable computer nowadays will only be noticeable if you use it tens of thousands of times)

Comment: the code is longer and tracing errors is more difficult, compare `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\testA{blub}\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\testB{}{blub}
\begin{document}xxx {\tracingmacros=1 \testA } xxx {\tracingmacros=1 \testB } \end{document}`

Comment: My advice is to check firstly how expansion works in TeX mechanism. look for `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` and such things in `The TeXbook` and try to create some commands there by `\def` (just as an alternative and training method of `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`)

Comment: BTW, is there any reason for `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{text}` (so without any argument) to not behave just as `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{text}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed. Isn't it improvable?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé how would you determine `text` was just text and did not have any commands that require protection?

Comment: what does improvable mean??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed. My concern was just to have a uniform way of defining variables and commands and not have to differentiate `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for the former and `\NewDocumentCommand` for the latter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I meant to make errors tracing of `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` as simple as `\newcommand`'s one.

Comment: The best tool for defining macros is `\def` or `\protected\def`. I need nothing more.

Comment: I wouldn't define commands like your \dst, this doesn't scale well and doesn't contain semantic information. I would define a command like `\people{dst}`, which would also have the benefit that spaces are not swallowed, something newbies don't like.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess `\people` would be designed to accept other arguments than just `dst`. In such a case, its definition would be out of the scope of a LaTeX course for beginners (some of the students are in their first year at university). For courses to intermediate LaTeX users, I insist on semantic information.

Comment: yes that would the plan. But even more importantly it would teach the students that you don't have to fill your preamble with hundreds of definitions that you can barely remember and which only will clash with some package.

Comment: Obviously, this advise to define variables as container of text is only for the main recurring strings of the document. I really don't see why not use this nice feature of LaTeX. And I guess many LaTeX users and packages (ab)use of it.

Comment: @wipet `\def` is too risky to be explained to beginners and even intermediate users: they might do `\def\par{whatever}`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé You can declare `\def\par{whatever}` or `\def\fi{finito}` without any problems in OpTeX because it uses its internal namespace. But, I understand, now we are talking about LaTeX which includes very old concept without different name spaces.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a container for text that can be delivered by expansion also in “full expansion” contexts, then `\NewDocumentCommand` is out of the question, because it defines a `\protected` command.

So the choice would be between `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and `\newcommand`. The latter has big advantages: delivering the contained text just requires one expansion step.

Besides, `\New(Expandable)DocumentCommand` is designed to do *parsing* of arguments in a cleaner way than with legacy LaTeX programming and not as a catch-all replacement for `\newcommand`, which will continue to exist. Argumentless macros (that is, containers) are best dealt with `\newcommand`, if you don't want to follow the path described below.

#### A better way

Actually, my suggestion is to use neither.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definecontainer}{mm}
 {
  \tl_new:c { l__denis_container_#1_tl }
  \tl_set:cn { l__denis_container_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecontainer}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l__denis_container_#1_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Or possibly a property list:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l_denis_container_prop

\NewDocumentCommand{\definecontainer}{mm}
 {
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_denis_container_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecontainer}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \l_denis_container_prop { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In either case you say `\definecontainer{foo}{whatever}` and `\usecontainer{foo}`.

The latter has the advantage that what's delivered by `\prop_item:Nn` is not subject to further expansion in full expansion contexts.

#### Real world application

Something like `\newcommand{\dst}{Dostoïevsky}` *seems* to simplify one's life, but that's not really true. After a few months, the same author of the essay will not remember what `\dst` means.

A possible better choice could be to use `\dostoievsky` as the name, but with the downside that you need `{}` after it, in order to preserve a following space.

A strategy like the one outlined above might help much better.

```
% boilerplate code
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_denis_names_prop
\NewDocumentCommand{\definename}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_denis_names_prop { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\name}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_denis_names_prop { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% define names
\definename{dostoievski}{Dostoïevsky}
```

In the body of the document you'd use

```
The Russian writer \name{dostoievsky} risked to be executed.
```

The name is there and the obvious convention is to remove capitalization and diacritics. This will be remembered much more easily.

For `\century` you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\century}{m}
 {
  % make the argument lowercase
  \textsc{\text_lowercase:n{#1}}
  % add the suffix
  \denis_century_suffix:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \denis_century_suffix:n
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { \str_foldcase:n { #1 } }
   { {i}{\ier} }
   { \ieme }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\century{i} \century{I} \century{xiv} \century{XIV}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More complicated than using an optional argument? Perhaps, but it makes life much easier.

Comment: I see the point but what I'm after is not for so experimented users: I'm after what to teach to newbies or intermediate users. I edited my question (at the end) in order to explain the context.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé What's wrong in using `\newcommand`?

Comment: `\newcommand` is less flexible: only one optional argument, no direct way to test special values  (to be compared to `\IfNoValueTF` and friends), no easy way to create starred versions of a command, etc.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Wasn't the question about commands *without* arguments?

Comment: If I'm right, for commands *with* arguments, `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't inadvisable and so I'm inclined to teach it. Then, I would at first glance consider to teach it for commands *without* arguments as well, since it is just a matter of an empty `⟨arg spec⟩` in `\NewDocumentCommand {⟨cmd⟩} {⟨arg spec⟩} {⟨code⟩}`.

Comment: About  `\dst` versus `\name{dostoievsky}`, one point is the former save your time, save your brain (to type this complicated and interminable name), save you from musculoskeletal problems (to type this complicated and interminable name), save you from nervous breakdown because of stupid compilation errors due to misspelling (of this complicated and interminable name). Plus I don't agree “the same author of the essay will not remember what `\dst` means” is a real issue: that's easy to remember and, if necessary, to retrieve.

Comment: As for the definitions of `\definename` and (yours) of `\century`, the fact is that they cannot reasonably be explained in a LaTeX course for beginners and intermediate users.

Comment: I think `\prop_put:Nn` in the second code block and `\prop_gput:Nn` in the third one are missing an additional n as argument specifier. So it should be `\prop_put:Nnn` and `\prop_gput:Nnn`, respectively.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandriaYou’re right

Answer (score 5):

In my LaTeX book, I have relegated `\newcommand` to a sidebar and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` to an appendix, preferring `\NewDocumentCommand` (and `\NewEnvironment`) for creating commands.

The biggest limitation *had* been that `tabularray`’s `expand=` option only worked with commands defined with `\def` or `\newcommand`¹ but a newer release has relaxed that restriction (and now I need to add a section to the manuscript, having seen this when checking for the name of the option).

I do like to put the argument specification on its own line with `\NewDocumentCommand` as it makes it harder to miss the empty spec when defining a command without arguments. Compare

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\dst}
   {}
   {Dostoïevsky}
```

and

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\dst}{}{Dostoïevsky}
```

---

1. Except commands defined with `\newcommand` that have optional arguments.

Answer (score 5):

We have two cases how to save a tokens list into TeX memory and restore it.
First case is defining macros without parameter and second case is using toks
registers:

```
                            save it:  \def\foo{text}    use it:   \foo
or:
declare it: \newtoks\foo    save it:  \foo={text}       use it:   \the\foo
```

The first case if fully expandable (in context of `\edef`, `\write`), the
second case expands only to `text`, but if `text` includes expandable
control sequences then they are not expanded in `\edef`, `\write` context. For example

```
\newtoks\foo  \foo={text: \the\dimen0 }  \edef\bar{... \the\foo ...}
```

then `\bar` is a macro with body: `... text: \the\dimen0 ...`.

Moreover, we can use the prefix `\protected` before `\def\foo` in order to
prohibit expansion of `\foo` in the `\edef`, `\write` context:

```
\protected\def\foo{text}  \edef\bar{... \foo ...}
```

then `\bar` is a macro with body: `... \foo ...`.

Note that the prefix `\long` can be used before `\def` too but its usage is
irrelevant when we define a macro without parameter. Only `\ifx` differs
between long and no-long macros even if they have no parameters.

LaTeX provides huge amount of macros which expand to these primitive
constructs (in order to make the world more difficult?). We can try to use them
and then to look at the meaning of declared control sequence:

```
\tt \parindent=0pt \parskip=10pt
\def\foo{text}               def: \meaning\foo     \par
\newtoks\foo  \foo={text}    toks: \meaning\foo    \par
\protected\def\foo{text}     protected def: \meaning\foo   \par

\let\foo=\undefined
\newcommand\foo{text}        newcommand: \meaning\foo   \par
\renewcommand\foo{text}      renewcommand: \meaning\foo  \par

\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{text}  DeclareRobustCommand: \meaning\foo  \par

\let\foo=\undefined
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{}{text}  NewDocumentCommand: \meaning\foo  \par
\let\foo=\undefined
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\foo{}{text}  NewExpandableDocumentCommand: \meaning\foo  \par
```

The result is:

[image: defs]

Note that macros declared by `\DeclareRobustCommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand`
and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` don't expand into its declared macro
body directly, but there is more complicated way to reach the declared macro body.
The declared macro body is invisible when we are using only `\meaning\foo`.
Tracing such macros (using positive `\tracingmacros`) is *very* inconvenient.

There are plenty of more macros doing the same or similar things in LaTeX's
Expl3 syntax, but I don't want to dig into them. They all run ultimately `\def` or handle with tokens registers.

Comment: +1 but I disagree on one point: While I am myself no fan of `expl3` macros, the fact that `\newcommand` checks whether the macro name has already been defined isn't a bad idea. So no, not all LaTeX macros are there to make the world more difficult. Only some `;-)`